# How to get caption of figure/table using table reference?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

How can I get the caption of figures and tables using their references?

Something along the lines of `\refcaption{tab:mytable}` would print `This is a pretty table.`, which is the caption of the table below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{lll}
    \toprule
    h1 & h2 & h3 \\
    \midrule
  \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \caption{This is a pretty table.}
    \label{tab:mytable}
  \endlastfoot
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
\end{longtabu}

Table~\ref{tab:mytable} looks good and its description is the following: \textbf{HOW TO GET DESC?}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: this facility may be provided by the `nameref` package.  check the package documentation for more information.  (i've never used the package for that purpose, so i'm not sure whether this selection really works.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: `\nameref{tab:mytable}` yields `This is a pretty table`, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you have something to play around with. I hope, you were planing to use the package `hyperref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{lll}
    \toprule
    h1 & h2 & h3 \\
    \midrule
  \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \caption{This is a pretty table.}
    \label{tab:mytable}
  \endlastfoot
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
\end{longtabu}

\autoref{tab:mytable} looks good and its description is the following: \enquote{\nameref{tab:mytable}.} You can also have a look at \Nameref{tab:mytable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The full document is using `hyperref`. Thanks!

Comment: Just `\usepackage{nameref}` would be sufficient; but `hyperref` loads it.